# How do I input the values from a query into a declare statement in order to loop through the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a distinct list from a table and then loop through each row from the result. I need to capture the value from each row, input it into a declare statement and then run another query. After the query is complete, it grabs a new value from the distinct list and repeats until all the values have been cycled through.

Here is what I have so far:

'''

```
Declare @FDIC_CERT int
Declare MY_CUR CURSOR
  LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
Select Distinct FDIC_Cert 
from bank.SOD_BranchList

OPEN MY_CUR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CUR INTO @FDIC_CERT
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin


    DECLARE @CERT INT 
    Set @CERT = @FDIC_CERT

    DECLARE @MyList TABLE (Value int)
    INSERT INTO @MyList SELECT DISTINCT UniqueID from bank.SOD_BranchList WHERE FDIC_CERT = @CERT

    DECLARE @COUNTER INT = 0;
    DECLARE @MAX INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @MyList)
    DECLARE @VALUE INT;

    WHILE @COUNTER < @MAX
    BEGIN

    SET @VALUE = (SELECT VALUE FROM
        (SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) [index], VALUE FROM @MyList) R
        ORDER BY R.[index] OFFSET @COUNTER
        ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY);

    PRINT @VALUE
    --delete from bank.DFC_SOD_Data
    insert into bank.Master_Competitor_List
    select 
    CAST(@Value AS int) ComparisonBranch,
    CAST(@CERT AS int) ComparisonBankID,
    a.BranchType ComparisonBranchType,
    a.Year,
    c.Distance,
    a.UniqueID ToBranch,
    CASE WHEN a.UniqueID=@Value THEN 'This Branch' 
    --WHEN a.FDIC_CERT IN (4666, 49600) THEN 'Other DFC Branches'
    ELSE 'Competitor' END Type,
    a.BranchName Branch,
    a.BranchType BranchType,
    a.FDIC_CERT BankID,
    a.BankName,
    a.Latitude,
    a.Longitude,
    a.Deposits
    --into bank.DFC_SOD_Data
    from bank.SOD_BranchList a
    inner join (
        select UniqueID_From, Year, Distance from bank.BranchDistanceMatrix_Copy WHERE ComparedTo = CAST(@VALUE as int) 
    ) c on a.UniqueID = c.UniqueID_From and 2021 = c.[YEAR]
    WHERE cast(c.Distance as float) <= 5

    SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
    PRINT @FDIC_CERT
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CUR INTO @FDIC_CERT

    END
    CLOSE MY_CUR
    DEALLOCATE MY_CUR
END
```

'''

I know that I should avoid using cursors so any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated. The error I'm currently getting is "A cursor with the name 'MY_CUR' does not exist"

Comment: This is almost never done with a loop procedurally.  Loops in SQL are done most often via joins.  That's probably what you really need to do.  Can you, in just a few words, explain the entire end goal of this logic?

Comment: For instance, if you need to calculate some values from t1 and insert those calculated values into t2, this can be done with something of the form: `INSERT INTO t2 ... SELECT ... FROM t1 ...;`  The SELECT can be nearly as complex as you require to generate just the rows to be inserted and nothing else, so that the result of the SELECT can be the source of your single INSERT statement.

Comment: My goal is to run a query on each Unique ID in the first query and inserting into a new table. Something like `INSERT INTO newtable SELECT . . .  FROM t2  WHERE Unique_ID = (Unique_ID from the first query);`. @JonArmstrong

Comment: That's done with: `INSERT INTO newtable SELECT ... FROM t1 JOIN (Select Distinct FDIC_Cert FROM bank.SOD_BranchList) AS dlist ON ...;`  Simple as that.  Any of your other logic can probably be expressed in CTE terms of the corresponding SELECT.  The procedural form usually isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use cursors when you don't need to. But if you are going to loop over rows use a cursor, not some other looping construct over single rows. If you want to use write this using row-by-row processing, you need two cursors: the outer cursor you have, and an inner cursor that replaces the WHILE @COUNTER < @MAX loop.

Using a nested cursor would look something like this:

```
Declare @FDIC_CERT int
Declare CERT_CUR CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
Select Distinct FDIC_Cert from bank.SOD_BranchList

OPEN CERT_CUR
FETCH NEXT FROM CERT_CUR INTO @FDIC_CERT
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @BRANCH_ID INT

    DECLARE BRANCH_CUR CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
    FOR 
    SELECT DISTINCT UniqueID from bank.SOD_BranchList WHERE FDIC_CERT = @FDIC_CERT

    OPEN BRANCH_CUR
    FETCH NEXT FROM BRANCH_CUR INTO @BRANCH_ID
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT @BRANCH_ID
        --delete from bank.DFC_SOD_Data
        insert into bank.Master_Competitor_List
        select 
        CAST(@BRANCH_ID AS int) ComparisonBranch,
        CAST(@FDIC_CERT AS int) ComparisonBankID,
        a.BranchType ComparisonBranchType,
        a.Year,
        c.Distance,
        a.UniqueID ToBranch,
        CASE WHEN a.UniqueID=@BRANCH_ID THEN 'This Branch' 
        --WHEN a.FDIC_CERT IN (4666, 49600) THEN 'Other DFC Branches'
        ELSE 'Competitor' END Type,
        a.BranchName Branch,
        a.BranchType BranchType,
        a.FDIC_CERT BankID,
        a.BankName,
        a.Latitude,
        a.Longitude,
        a.Deposits
        --into bank.DFC_SOD_Data
        from bank.SOD_BranchList a
        inner join (
            select UniqueID_From, Year, Distance from bank.BranchDistanceMatrix_Copy WHERE ComparedTo = CAST(@BRANCH_ID as int) 
        ) c on a.UniqueID = c.UniqueID_From and 2021 = c.[YEAR]
        WHERE cast(c.Distance as float) <= 5

        FETCH NEXT FROM BRANCH_CUR INTO @BRANCH_ID
    END
    CLOSE BRANCH_CUR
    DEALLOCATE BRANCH_CUR

    FETCH NEXT FROM CERT_CUR INTO @FDIC_CERT
END
CLOSE CERT_CUR
DEALLOCATE CERT_CUR
```

But since you're not calling some existing stored procedure for each row, this should be straightforward to do in a single query, something like:

```
    with b as
    (
       SELECT DISTINCT FDIC_CERT, UniqueID BRANCH_ID
       from bank.SOD_BranchList c
       join bank.SOD_BranchList b
         on c.FDIC_CERT = b.FDIC_CERT
    )
    insert into bank.Master_Competitor_List
    select 
    CAST(b.BRANCH_ID AS int) ComparisonBranch,
    CAST(b.FDIC_CERT AS int) ComparisonBankID,
    a.BranchType ComparisonBranchType,
    a.Year,
    c.Distance,
    a.UniqueID ToBranch,
    CASE WHEN a.UniqueID=b.BRANCH_ID THEN 'This Branch' 
    --WHEN a.FDIC_CERT IN (4666, 49600) THEN 'Other DFC Branches'
    ELSE 'Competitor' END Type,
    a.BranchName Branch,
    a.BranchType BranchType,
    a.FDIC_CERT BankID,
    a.BankName,
    a.Latitude,
    a.Longitude,
    a.Deposits
    --into bank.DFC_SOD_Data
    from bank.SOD_BranchList a
    inner join (
        select UniqueID_From, Year, Distance from bank.BranchDistanceMatrix_Copy WHERE ComparedTo = CAST(b.BRANCH_ID as int) 
    ) c on a.UniqueID = c.UniqueID_From and 2021 = c.[YEAR]
    WHERE cast(c.Distance as float) <= 5
```

Comment: This query seems to be more in line with what I'm trying to achieve but I think that it might be a little off. My goal is to run the query after the 'insert into bank.Master_Competitor_List' line for every unique FDIC_Cert number in the list created from the 'SELECT DISTINCT FDIC_CERT, UniqueID BRANCH_ID from bank.SOD_BranchList' @DavidBrowne